# OpenJMS redelivers and delays messages

Tags: java, jms, openmq, openjms

I have a consumer of a JMS queue. An exception may occur during the consumption, and I need to trigger the process again.
I have two preliminary plans:

1. Set acknowledge to [`javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE). `javax.jms.Message#acknowledge()` is called to delete the message when processing succeeds, and `javax.jms.Session#recover()` is called to tell OpenMQ to redeliver the message when processing fails. But I couldn't find a way to set the maximum number of redeliveries and the time interval between redeliveries.
2. Set acknowledge to [`javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE). Send a new message (containing the original message and the processing times) to a new queue  each time an exception occurs, and I want to be able to set the delay time. However, I can't find a way to set the delay time of the message.

Comment: For option #2 you could look at the JMS 2.0 delayed delivery feature, just put back to the same queue with a delay.   IBM MQ JMS implements a poison message feature where if the backout count of the message exceeds a threshold,  the message will be moved to a backout queue,  i don't know if OpenMQ implements something similar.

Comment: I've implemented delay message through OpenMQ.
I started with a dependency package: `com.sun.messaging.mq:imq:4.6-b01`which did not implement the JMS2.0 API, and then found another dependency package `org.glassfish.mq:imq:5.1` based on your comment.
Do you know why he changed the group id?  @JoshMc